# GIT - get last commit for folder from Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I need to get last commit hash for some folders during Jenkins build.

Locally I use for it this command

```
git log --no-merges -1 --pretty=format:%H --output=c:/Temp/com.itextpdf.lastCommit -- com.itextpdf
```

This works fine and correct commit is written into the file.

During Jenkins build I'm using this groovy script

```
dir("${prj}")
{
    echo "Getting last commits in manually numbered plugins"
    manuallyNumberedPlugins.each{
       echo "plugin: $it"
       String output = "${TEST_TEMP_DIR}/${it}.lastCommit"
       bat script: "${gitTool} log --no-merges -1 --pretty=format:%%H --output=$output -- $it"
    }
    echo "Done"
}
```

which executes following command

```
D:\Jenkins\workspace\GX_Branch\java>D:\Apps\Git.2.21.0\bin\git.exe log --no-merges -1 --pretty=format:%H --output=D:\Jenkins\workspace\GX_Branch/tmp/com.itextpdf.lastCommit -- com.itextpdf
```

But latest commit to whole repository is written into the output file instead of last commit to com.itextpdf folder.

Answer (score 0):

I've overlooked that we use shallow copy with only last revision.